# Minizinc program complains of failed assertion in global_cardinality

Tags: minizinc

I was trying to solve this problem in Minizinc, taken from [Puzzle taken from Gardner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35485185/puzzle-taken-from-gardner/35494040#35494040) :

> Ten cells numbered 0,...,9 inscribe a 10-digit number such that each
>   cell, say i, indicates the total number of occurrences of the digit i
>   in this number. Find this number. The answer is 6210001000.

I solved it, and the code is working fine with Gecode:

```
int: n=9;
set of int: N=0..n;
array[N] of var N: cell;

include "globals.mzn";
constraint global_cardinality(cell, N, cell);
solve satisfy;

output [show(cell), "\n", show(index_set(cell)), " -- ", show(index_set(N))];
```

Output from Gecode:

```
[6, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
0..9 -- 1..10
----------
==========
```

However, G12 solvers complain about a assertion failed in global_cardinality:

> in call 'assert'   Assertion failed: global_cardinality: cover and
>   counts must have identical index sets

True, as the output from Gecode shows, N is 1..10 and cell is 0..9. So my questions are:

- Why Gecode is working? Different implementation or my program is buggy but I was lucky?
- How can I fix the program to work with G12 or to make it robust/correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you start your array on 0. While it is technically correct to do so, it is preferred and recommended to start your arrays at 1 (standard in MiniZinc). As you can see there is still some solvers that do not fully support arrays that do not start at 1. There have also been a few bugs connected to the use of arrays that do not start at 0.

I get the same error on g12cpx as you do but modifying the array to

```
array[1..10] of var N: cell;
```

gives me the right result.

Comment: Thank you, this works fine. I had a misunderstanding of how sets work. I assumed that it should start the array at 0 because of the definition of the problem, that is, it should start with cell[0] containing the number of zeros, but I see now the difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by adding array1d():

```
 global_cardinality(cell,array1d(0..n,[i | i in N]), cell);
```

The reason Gecode works but not G12/fd, is that Gecode has its own MiniZinc definition of the constraint which don't include the cardinality check.